# realloc is not reallocating memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, realloc

```
int _add_item( char * _key, void * _value, int item, dict *_dic ){

  printf("%lu", sizeof(_dic->key));
  printf(" + %lu\n", sizeof(_key));
  printf("%lu\n", (sizeof(_dic->key) + sizeof (_key)) );
  _dic->key = (char **) realloc (_dic->key, (sizeof _dic->key) + (sizeof _key));
  _dic->value = (void **) realloc (_dic->value, (sizeof _dic->value)+ (sizeof _value));
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof(_dic->key) );
  getchar();
  _dic->key[item] = _key;
  _dic->value[item] = _value;
  puts(_dic->key[item]);
  printf("%i\n", get_dic_len(* _dic) );
  getchar();

  return 1;
}
```

Out:

```
8 + 8
16
8
```

realloc is not reallocating memory, it was 8 bytes, i tried to reallocate to 16 bytes but it remained 8 bytes

Comment: Are you sure that you want `sizeof *_dic->value` instead of `sizeof _dic->value` in the `realloc` call?

Comment: `printf("%lu", sizeof(_dic->key));` is wrong and invokes undefined behavior.  The proper format specifier for the `size_t` that `sizeof()` returns is `%zu`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(_dic->key)` computes the size of a *pointer*, which is constant - 8 bytes in your case. *All pointers on your machine are 8 bytes*, no matter how much memory they point to.